# Join multiple DataFrames in parallel using sparksql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have `df1`, `df2`, `df3`... upto `df10`. All the df have `uniqueId` column common and each df has another column

`df1=> (uniqueId,firstName)`

`df2=> (uniqueId,middleName)`

`df3=> (uniqueId,lastName)`
and so on..

Currently I am storing the data frames in two lists

 `df1` to `df5` in `list1 = ListBuffer[DataFrame]()` 
 and

 `df6` to `df10` in `list2 = ListBuffer[DataFrame]()`

followed by

```
val finalDf1 = list1
      .reduceLeft((df1, df2) => df1.join(df2, uniqueIdentifier, FULL_OUTER))

 val finalDf2 = list2
      .reduceLeft((df1, df2) => df1.join(df2, uniqueIdentifier, FULL_OUTER))

finalDf1
      .join(finalDf2, uniqueIdentifier, FULL_OUTER).show()
```

In this case still `df1` to `df5` join is sequential, similarly `df6` to `df10`. How can I avoid this sequential join and parallelize as must as possible?

Comment: you don't need to parallelize it. `.join` call isn't doing very much besides manipulating some metadata, and creating a plan. The actual work happens inside `.show`

Comment: @Dima, yes, but the plan shows that df1 join df2 and output of that joins with df3 and the output of all the 3 joins with df4 and so on which is pretty much sequential.

Comment: oh, I see what you are saying, but don't think you can actually do that. Could be wrong, AFAIK, all join implementations in spark operate in terms of "left" and "right" dataset, there are always two. It seems like it would be very tricky to implement otherwise, especially, with types other than full, but even with full join, that seems the easiest, realizing that condition is actually the same and that you can shuffle everything the same way ahead of time seems non-trivial.